# /usr/bin/ld: unrecognized option '-plugin' error

Tags: c++, linux

Dear I am new in C++ and Linux as well
I am getting the folliwng error while compiling a programm

/usr/bin/ld: unrecognized option '-plugin'

/usr/bin/ld: use the --help option for usage information

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

The installed gcc compiler is 
gcc version 4.4.5 (Debian 4.4.5-8)
any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: How you´re compiling?

Comment: its a collection of many files...using command make all

Comment: Sadly, this error is showing up in other places, like [“C compiler cannot create executables” in libssh2 during npm install](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38751514).

Comment: It is ridiculous that this question is closed.

Comment: I have edited the question so that it can be re-opened. But cutting to the chase: the answer is that you need to use a newer version of `ld`. The linker is not provided by gcc but instead by the binutils package.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Makefile` must be passing the `-plugin` option to the linker - it's your `make` configuration that you have to fix. There are three locations to check off the top of my head:

- Look for a `-plugin` option being inserted into the `LDFLAGS` variable. The contents of that variable are passed straight to the linker as arguments.
- Look for a `-Wl,-plugin` option being inserted into the `CFLAGS` variable. That variable is passed as an argument list to the compiler, and `gcc` uses the `-Wl,...` option to pass arguments to the linker.
- Look for either option being used in a direct call to `ld` or `gcc` (or `cc`, or `c++` or...).

Bottom line: `grep` your `make` configuration files and any scripts used in your build system for `-plugin` and make sure that option only goes where it should.

Comment: option four: Your version of the linker is too old for the version of gcc that you are using. The linker is provided by the `binutils` package. Install a newer version (e.g. binutils/7.30) and you will find that this error message goes away.