# "C compiler cannot create executables" in libssh2 during npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, libssh2, gcc4.9, nodegit

I got the following error during npm install of [nodegit](http://www.nodegit.org/):

```
> nodegit@0.15.1 preinstall /home/mhu/nodegit
> node lifecycleScripts/preinstall

[nodegit] Running pre-install script
[nodegit] npm@2 installed, pre-loading required packages
[nodegit] Configuring libssh2.
{ [Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c /home/mhu/nodegit/vendor/libssh2/configure --with-libssl-prefix=/home/mhu/nodegit/vendor/openssl/openssl
configure: error: in `/home/mhu/nodegit/vendor/libssh2':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
]
  killed: false,
  code: 77,
  signal: null,
  cmd: '/bin/sh -c /home/mhu/nodegit/vendor/libssh2/configure --with-libssl-prefix=/home/mhu/nodegit/vendor/openssl/openssl' }
configure: error: in `/home/mhu/nodegit/vendor/libssh2':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

[nodegit] ERROR - Could not finish preinstall
{ [Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c /home/mhu/nodegit/vendor/libssh2/configure --with-libssl-prefix=/home/mhu/nodegit/vendor/openssl/openssl
configure: error: in `/home/mhu/nodegit/vendor/libssh2':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
]
  killed: false,
  code: 77,
  signal: null,
  cmd: '/bin/sh -c /home/mhu/nodegit/vendor/libssh2/configure --with-libssl-prefix=/home/mhu/nodegit/vendor/openssl/openssl' }
```

Can someone help me with this? Is it because a permission issue that caused the C compiler to bot able to create executables?

my environment:

os: `centos-release-6-8.el6.centos.12.3.x86_64`

gcc: `4.9.1`

openssl: `openssl-1.0.1e-48.el6.x86_64`

libssh2: `libssh2-1.4.2-2.el6_7.1.x86_64`

node: `v4.4.7`

npm: `2.15.8`

`gcc -v` gives:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/packages/encap/gcc-4.9.1/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../gcc-4.9.1/configure --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --enable-shared --disable-libstdcxx-pch --enable-lto --enable-libgomp --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-tls --with-gmp --with-mpfr --with-mpc --with-libelf
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.1 (GCC)
```

Here is the part in config.log in /home/mhu/nodegit/vendor/libssh2  that gives error:

```
configure:3429: $? = 0
configure:3418: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/packages/encap/gcc-4.9.1/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../gcc-4.9.1/configure --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --enable-shared --disable-libstdcxx-pch --enable-lto --enable-libgomp --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-tls --with-gmp --with-mpfr --with-mpc --with-libelf
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.1 (GCC)
configure:3429: $? = 0
configure:3418: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3429: $? = 1
configure:3418: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3429: $? = 1
configure:3449: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3471: gcc  -I/home/mhu/nodegit/vendor/openssl/openssl/include  conftest.c  >&5
/usr/bin/ld: unrecognized option '-plugin'
/usr/bin/ld: use the --help option for usage information
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:3475: $? = 1
configure:3513: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "libssh2"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libssh2"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "-"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "libssh2 -"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "libssh2-devel@cool.haxx.se"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "libssh2"
| #define VERSION "-"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
|
| int
| main ()
| {
|
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3518: error: in `/home/mhu/nodegit/vendor/libssh2':
configure:3520: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Comment: It seems like you don't have a compiler installed for your CPU architecture? Can you include the full output of `gcc -v` in your question?

Comment: Also, do you have the `CC` environment variable set (`echo $CC`)?

Comment: @mscdex no I didn't set $CC.

Comment: @mscdex I'm running NodeGit in a CentOS build server, and here is gcc version on  that server: Using built-in specs. COLLECT_GCC=gcc COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/packages/encap/gcc-4.9.1/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-‌​linux-gnu/4.9.1/lto-wrapper Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu Configured with: ../gcc-4.9.1/configure --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --enable-shared --disable-libstdcxx-pch --enable-lto --enable-libgomp --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-tls --with-gmp --with-mpfr --with-mpc --with-libelf Thread model: posix gcc version 4.9.1 (GCC)

Comment: @jww Sorry I have just pasted the portion in config.log that shows the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `config.log`, your problem is:

```
/usr/bin/ld: unrecognized option '-plugin'
```

This appears to be an obscure error. Its discussed in two questions on Stack Overflow. The most promising question is [How to fix “unrecognized option '-plugin`” when using gdc to compile D program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27813341).

To fix this in Autotools (which produces `config.log` and friends), you need to do the following:

```
export CPPFLAGS="-fno-use-linker-plugin"
export CFLAGS="-fno-use-linker-plugin"
export CXXFLAGS="-fno-use-linker-plugin"
```

Then, in the Autotools world, you would:

```
./configure --with-libssl-prefix=/home/mhu/nodegit/vendor/openssl/openssl ...
```

You can sometimes get away with adding the flag to the compiler:

```
export CC=gcc -fno-use-linker-plugin
export CXX=g++ -fno-use-linker-plugin
```

Unfortunately, that's where my knowledge ends. I don't know what you should do for *npm*. This looks like the question to turn to for the answer: [How to pass options to dependent package installs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34822510/608639)